# JQuery hide button when scrolling to top of window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Do I need to wrap the anchor in a `div`, and then use the `div` id for the fade? If `$(this)` is for `#scrollToTop` can I somehow use `this.fade`? I cannot seem to get this simple JQuery to take effect. I would like to hide `#scollToTop` until scrolled. Should I be wrapping this in a `div` and manipulating the div?

```
<a href="#" id="scrollToTop"></a>


$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollToTop() > 75) {
        $('#scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});​
```

Comment: What is the problem you are experiencing? Do you get errors in your console? Can you build a fiddle / snippet we can use for testing?

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. I will slow down and stick to one task at a time from now on, and of course, use the console to debug. Thank you cale_b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you aren't getting it to work is due to *errors in your code*.

**Tip:** learn to use you're browser's developer console - it is an absolute necessity when developing in javascript.  You had an error - `scrollToTop` is not a function. (You wanted `scrollTop`).  That was the majority of the problem.

To answer your questions:

In jQuery, `$(this)` refers to the element that triggered the event.  Therefore, in your code, `$(this)` refers to `$(window)`, and therefore `$(this).scrollTop` is  measuring the `scrollTop` position of the window (the same as writing `$(window).scrollTop`).

Since it's *not* referencing `#scrollToTop`, then no, you cannot use `$(this).fade` to hide the button.  You are doing it properly.

No, you do not need to wrap it in a `div` and manipulate that.

Additionally, I've added a [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) call to ensure the button is hidden on initial load, if the page is within the range where it should be hidden.  (Trigger "triggers" the event you are watching - in this case `scroll` - immediately, so the callback runs, and the button will be hidden / displayed as appropriate).

Here's a [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/xpvt214o/103902/), and the relevant code below:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    // scrollToTop is not a function - changed to scrollTop
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 75) {
        $('#scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#scrollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
}).trigger('scroll');
```